# In ffmpeg: Can't get peak bitrate values within 10% error tolerance for HLS playlist files

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, bitrate

I'm using ffmpeg to produce several HLS variant playlists from an .mp4 file. When I check master.m3u8 file with mediastreamvalidator I get:

> Error: Measured peak bitrate compared to master playlist declared value exceeds error tolerance

I understand that the error percentage needs to be less than 10%, and figured it out on 1 variant but not the three others. I've spent quite a bit of time adjusting the -maxrate and the -buffsize but the error percentage change is minimal. Beginning to wonder if I'm misunderstanding something?

This is the latest of what I enter:

```
ffmpeg -i FHVid.mp4 \
-b:v:0 5000k -maxrate 5250k -bufsize 5500k -profile:v main -c:v h264 -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 \
-b:v:1 2800k -maxrate 2940k -bufsize 3100k -profile:v main -c:v h264 -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 \
-b:v:2 1400k -maxrate 1540k -bufsize 1700k -profile:v main -c:v h264 -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 \
-b:v:3 800k -maxrate 840k -bufsize 1050k -profile:v main -c:v h264 -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 \
-b:a:0 192k \
-b:a:1 128k \
-b:a:2 128k \
-b:a:3 96k \
-c:a aac -ar 48000 -keyint_min 48 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 0:a \
-f hls -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0  v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3" \
-master_pl_name FHVidmaster.m3u8 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_segment_filename 'file_%v_%03d.ts' out_%v.m3u8
```

but I've also tried max rates that seem to be more standard

```
-b:v:0 5000k -maxrate 5500k -bufsize 6500k
-b:v:1 2800k -maxrate 3080k -bufsize 3200k
-b:v:2 1400k -maxrate 1540k -bufsize 1900k
-b:v:3 800k -maxrate 880k -bufsize 1050k
```

The latest error message:

```
Error: Measured peak bitrate compared to master playlist declared value exceeds error tolerance
--> Detail:  Measured: 1111.54 kb/s, Master playlist: 1680.80 kb/s, Error: 33.87%
--> Source:  /Users/Bun/Documents/CODING/CosmicPerspectiveAssets/01-FalconHeavy/HLS/FHVidmaster.m3u8
--> Compare: out_2.m3u8

--> Detail:  Measured: 1178.21 kb/s, Master playlist: 5711.20 kb/s, Error: 79.37%
--> Source:  /Users/Bun/Documents/CODING/CosmicPerspectiveAssets/01-FalconHeavy/HLS/FHVidmaster.m3u8
--> Compare: out_0.m3u8

--> Detail:  Measured: 1109.03 kb/s, Master playlist: 3220.80 kb/s, Error: 65.57%
--> Source:  /Users/Bun/Documents/CODING/CosmicPerspectiveAssets/01-FalconHeavy/HLS/FHVidmaster.m3u8
--> Compare: out_1.m3u8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated on the -maxrate and -buffsize for variant playlists 0, 1, and 2. No adjustment I make seems to make any difference.

Comment: Which encoder? `h264` will prioritize among the available h264 encoders but not pick a specific one.

Comment: Use libx264 and set the vbv values.